# PublishSubject calls expensive function for all Observers

Tags: android, rx-java2, publishsubject

I have a specific scenario where I have implemented an PublishSubject to emit items based on a custom Event. For each item that will be emitted I also need to persist that value (an expensive operation).
What I'm trying to achieve is to have a function (like the `map`) that will be called once for all the observers, and afterwards the item to be received by each observer through the `onNext()` method.

The subject:

```
static final PublishSubject<SomeResult> commonSubject = PublishSubject.create()
```

The trigger(emitting items):

```
commonSubject.onNext(new SomeResult())
```

Expose the subject(will be used by the controller):

```
public static Observable<SomeResult> observeResults() {
    return commonSubject.share();
}
```

Controller:

```
public Observable<SomeResult> observeResults() {
    return CustomConsumer.observeResults()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.single());
}
```

Subscribers:

```
CustomControllerResult.observeResults().subscribe(result -> doSomething());
CustomControllerResult.observeResults().subscribe(result -> doSomethingElse());
```

Each Observer receives the items as expected, but if I add the expensive operation to the controller, this will be called for each observer(something that I do not want):

```
public Observable<SomeResult> observeResults() {
    return CustomConsumer.observeResults()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
            .compose(persistResult())
            .compose(logResult())
            .share();
}
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: have you tried moving `share()` AFTER the expensive operation in the chain?

Comment: Yes, doesn't seem to affect it. (I actually forgot to add it in the code above - I edited it now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time `observeResults()` is called it creates a new Observable with the `share` operator. But the Observable created is not being shared with the subscribers.

You can change your code to:

```
Observable<SomeResult> observable = CustomControllerResult.observeResults()
observable.subscribe(result -> doSomething());
observable.subscribe(result -> doSomethingElse());
```

Or you can change the `observeResults` method to return the shared Observable:

```java
static final PublishSubject<SomeResult> commonSubject = PublishSubject.create()

static final Observable<SomeResult> observable = commonSubject
    .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
    .compose(persistResult())
    .compose(logResult())
    .share();

public static Observable<SomeResult> observeResults() {
    return observable;
}
```

Comment: This was what I also suspected it happens. Great tip for actually sharing the observable. Thank you.